# Display only duplicates from a 2D array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to use Split and Filter to display ONLY the duplicate zip codes within a column list of zip codes. Column A shows location name (irrevelant) and column B is a comma-separated list of zips. In column C+ I want only the zip codes that are a duplicate of the entire column B to be shown.

| Location Name | Zip Code List | [Output]Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Home 1 | 37075,37066,37072 | 37075 | 37066 | 37072 |
| Home 2 | 37066,37072 | 37066 | 37072 |  |
| Home 3 | 37072,37112,37089 | 37072 |  |  |
| Home 4 | 37075,37067 | 37075 |  |  |

In this case above, Column C, D, E are the expected output.

I currently have the following in cell C2
`=filter(split(B2,","),arrayformula(countif(split(B2,","),B2)>1))`

But this is not working.

Comment: These must be really big homes to have multiple zip codes! I don’t understand what “In column C+ I want only the zip codes that are a duplicate of the entire column B to be shown.” means so please include a very small data subset with a hardcoded desired before and after output.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCamper, updated the question. However the duplicates could be listed in a single column comma-separated as well. Either way is fine.

Comment: Home 1 is broken out but home 3 and 4 are only breaking out the first zip code? This is the behavior you want? Why?

Comment: This is the result I am wanting.  I want to see what zip codes in column B have duplicates in the rest of the column.

Comment: So when a new line is entered, it will display if there is a duplicate zip code that the user needs to review and see which location they actually want that zip code to be in because they cannot have duplicates.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SPLIT` column B by `,` and pass the `s`plit `arr`ay to `COUNTIF` as both `range` and `criterion` to get the count of each element in the array. `IF` count>1, return the array, else return nothing.

##### Sample:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  LAMBDA(
    s_arr,
    IF(
      COUNTIF(s_arr,s_arr)>1,
      s_arr,
    )
  )(SPLIT(B2:B6,","))
)
```

Comment: This works because the first parameter of countif accepts a range and ignores the arrayformula loop but the second parameter criterion part doesn’t pass it as an array but loops through all the elements the way you would normally expect with arrayformula?

Comment: I don’t understand/fully visualize how s_arr can search the entire array with all its rows and columns and simultaneously s_arr can be just one element.

Comment: @CodeCamper Maybe this will help visualize: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF({1,2;3,4;1,2},{1,2;3,4}))` Try changing values one by one.

Comment: @JeffSasse Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of this post.

Answer (score 2):

Place this in a cell somewhere which will be your helper cell to have a master list of all zip codes: (b being the column which has all your zip codes)

```
=textjoin(",",1,B2:B)
```

Then enter this in the header (usually row 1) of your data: (replace $A$6 with the cell you out the helper cell above and replace $b$2:$b$5 with your zip column)

```
={"dupe zips";arrayformula(byrow(Split($B$2:$B$5, ",",0,1),lambda(z,textjoin(",",1,iferror(if(find(z,substitute($A$6,z,"",1)),z,"z"),"")))))}
```